# IBM Message Broker (IIB) Node can't send credentials to MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I have a local MQ which my IIB connects to in client mode (i.e. not as a trusted application). I've set check client connection security on in the QM and now the IIB can't connect because it doesn't send a password and it's sending the wrong username (by default it uses the user that the process starts with). I've seen lots of documentation around setting dbparms mq::*. I could be wrong that but that only seems to affect the MQ Input and Output nodes ? Not the actual broker and it's config manager connections to MQ?

However, I've tried setting those values so that all client connection to my QMGR get a user/passwd but it still comes across as failing and I can see in the MQ logs that it's trying to connect using the userid that the IIB process was started with (and presumably without a password).
So, how do I get IIB to ALWAYS send a user/passwd to MQ when connecting the node/config mgr to the QM using client connections??

Clarification: 
I have set mq::MQ -u -p and still the node attempts to connect to the QMGR using the ID that the MQSI process is started with and not the -u param. I have no execution groups and (of course) no flows in my broker so this can only be a core IIB component that's attempting the connection.

Answer (score 1):

According to the IBM Integration Bus v10.0.0.10 Knowledge Center page "[Connecting to a secured WebSphere MQ queue manager](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc28631_.htm)" you can set this in three ways:

1. On each MQ Node by specifying a `Security identity` property.
2. For all MQ connections to a named queue manager
3. For all MQ connections.

The order of which ID will be used is the same as above, so if you have a ID setup for all queue managers, you can override it for a specific queue manager or a specific MQ Node.

If you have a queue manager you are already connecting to called for example `IIBQM`, you could specify the following command so that all connections to that queue manager would use the specified `username` and `password`.

```
mqsisetdbparms integrationNodeName -n mq::QMGR::IIBQM -u username -p password
```

The KC page tells how to set it all three ways.  If you have any specific questions please update your question by clicking edit and add more details and I can update my answer.

Comment: Hi, I obviously didn't make myself clear - I have already done those changes and the broker is still attempting to connect to MQ on startup as the process owner user - not the user that I set in MQ::* - I don't think those parms work for anything other than MQ Nodes themselves - not the Broker itself??

Comment: What version of IIB?

Comment: 10.0.0.9 and MQ 9.

Comment: Are you using "[file-based or queue-based authorization](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bn28614_.htm)"?

Answer (score 1):

Hurrah - I've worked this out !

Although, I had not enabled chcklocal or chckclnt MQ, the fact that I had a idpwldap authinfo set meant that MQ was going to LDAP to find out who the user was that I was logging in with (presumably so that it could check what group permissions it had). So, I had to put my local user into LDAP and set its group.

This got my broker working (with no execution groups or flows). Once I deployed my simple mqinput and MQ output node flow it failed due to authorisations using the same ID. I could then see that it was binding locally and not as a client (which i had first considered). Phew - all done. So, to review: the answer was to put the user id that the mqsi bip/bipbroker process runs under into LDAP. Then give various MQ permissions so that the broker NODE and it's MQ flow NODES could connect to MQ correctly and put/get etc.

thanks for your help - and maybe this will help someone else in the future when someone puts on MQ security and they have a local QM with IIB.

Comment: If you use file based security the IIB should have no need to connect to MQ locally.  If you want to use client connection for the queues that your flows put/get from then you need to specify the details like channel, hostname, port, and username and password.